# Updating all array values toUpper via collection.update in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Mongo shell> db.version : 4.2.6

Trying to update all documents in a collection with:
categories array[]. `["value1", "value2"]` into `["VALUE1", "VALUE2"]`
By using a placeholder `$[e]`

Could use a little help on how to rewrite below or an explanation.
thanks.

```
db.Article.update( {},{ $set :{ "categories.$[e]" : { $toUpper: "e"  }}},{ multi: true, arrayFilters : [ {"e" : { $regex:'.+'  } } ]} )

WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 52,
                "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$toUpper' in 'categories.0.$toUpper' is not valid for storage."
        }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting MongoDB version >= `4.2` update operations in MongoDB can execute aggregation pipeline in them, Check : [update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline). So you can try below query :

```
db.Article.update(
  { $expr: { $eq: [{ $type: "$categories" }, "array"] } }, // Condition that checks `categories` exists & is an array.
  [
    {
      $set: {
        categories: {
          $map: {
            input: "$categories",
            in: { $toUpper: "$$this" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  { multi: true }
);
```

Just in case if couple of your elements in `categories` array are not of type **string** (If `categories` array is mix of numbers & strings) then in `in` part of `$map` you can have a condition like :: `{$cond : [{$eq : [{$type : '$$this'},'string']},{ $toUpper: "$$this" } ,'$$this']}`

**Test :** Test aggregation pipeline here : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6bKX891WRlw)

**Note :** You can use `.updateMany()` instead of using `.update()` with option `{multi : true}`.

Comment: Thank you very much! also for pointing to the docs  ... to be honest also the part I did not fully read because of the words  aggregation / pipelines combined with $gte , $inc  and assumed it had to do with calculus and aggregates ... oh well another lesson learned.  Much appreciated.